# PHP simple math captcha function

Tags: php, captcha

I am trying to write a simple math captcha function to validate a form which will alow users to post a specific article on a blog.

The function:

```
  function create_captcha($num1, $num2) {
        $num1 = (int)$num1;
        $num2 = (int)$num2;
        $rand_num_1 = mt_rand($num1, $num2);
        $rand_num_2 = mt_rand($num1, $num2);
        $result = $rand_num_1 + $rand_num_2;
        return $result;
    }
```

Form:

```
<h2 class="email_users_headers">Post Article</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="post_blog_entry">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="title... *"><br>
        <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="content... *"></textarea><br>
        <?php echo create_captcha(1, 20) . ' + ' . create_captcha(1, 20) . ' = '; ?>
        <input type="text" name="captcha_results" size="2">
        <input type="hidden" name='num1' value='<?php echo create_captcha(1, 20); ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name='num2' value='<?php echo create_captcha(1, 20); ?>'>
        <input type="submit" name="publish" value="post entry" id="publish">
    </form>
```

Captcha validation:

```
if (empty($_POST['captcha_results']) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Please enter captcha';
            } else {
                if ($_POST['captcha_results'] != $_POST['num1'] + $_POST['num2']) {
                    $errors[] = 'Incorrect captcha';
                }
            }
```

I know this is totally wrong because no matter the input the result is always incorrect. Could someone point me in the right direction as I don't have any experience with PHP.

Comment: Have you logged your three POST values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you run `create_captcha(1, 20)` it generates different values.

1. create_captcha(1, 20) - 3 + 7 = 10
2. create_captcha(1, 20) - 6 + 11 = 17
   ...

And in your form you call it **4** times.

I think you should do this:

```
$num1 = create_captcha(1, 20);
$num2 = create_captcha(1, 20);
```

And use this values in your form:

```
<textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="content... *"></textarea><br>
<?php echo $num1 . ' + ' . $num2 . ' = '; ?>
<input type="text" name="captcha_results" size="2">
<input type="hidden" name='num1' value='<?php echo $num1; ?>'>
<input type="hidden" name='num2' value='<?php echo $num2; ?>'>
```

Comment: I have tried all that, however when comparing`$_POST['captcha_results']` with `$_POST['num1'] + $_POST['num2']` - this is always returning the number 50, while the captcha function is generating random numbers all the time. Do I need to remove something from the function as well?

Comment: I have replaced the !== with != and it works now. Is this the correct approach? Why did it work with != but not with !==? Thanks, I can't vote your solution up just yet, not enough rep

Comment: While `!=` checks only values of variables, `!==` also checks it's types.

Answer (score 0):

Having the two numbers in a hidden input allows bots to solve it through javascript (see Pseudocode)

`code = hidden[0].value + hidden[1].value`

To mitigate this, consider multiplying the value, and using base64. This will slow down the bots.

You can mitigate it further by providing a decoy hidden input

```
$num3 = mt_rand(0,20);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="num3" value="'.$num3.'">';
```

I like the idea a lot though.